# Split an instruction into more than four sub instructions?

Tags: cpu-pipelines

0

I am learning about the instructions-set in my computer science course, and I am wondering if it is possible to split an instruction into more than four sub-instructions.

Thank you

Comment: A vector instruction (e.g. Intel SSE, ARM NEON) could be replaced by multiple scalar instructions that do the same thing. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: are you thinking about microinstructions?

Comment: What would prohibit that ?

Answer (score 2):

Many processors with complex instructions split them up internally into less complex instructions and execute those. Often these are called “micro-OPs”. Intel x86 processors often split one instruction into four "micro-OPs". I think ARM 32 bit processors split "load multiple registers" and "store multiple registers" into up to 8 instructions; I might be wrong there. There is no reason why an instruction couldn’t be split into more.

Whether having instructions of that complexity is a good idea is a different question.

For vector instructions, which are expensive to implement, it is quite possible to split for example one 512 bit instruction into eight 64 bit instructions. Say you have a 16 core processor. Implementing 512 bit vector instructions in every core is expensive. So you could have two cores implementing the full 512 bit instructions, 14 cores splitting them into eight instructions (saving lots of money), and the OS switches threads using these instructions a lot to the two big cores.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if instructions can be split into smaller instructions, then the answer is no.  That's not how instructions work.
Instructions are a sequence of bits (the opcode) and an operand (the data to be operated on).  The operand can be an immediate value, a register, or a memory address.  The operand can be encoded in the instruction, or it can be stored in a register or memory.  There's no way to split the instruction into two smaller instructions.
If you're asking if instructions can be split into more than four sub-instructions, then you may want to look at instruction pipelines.  Instructions are executed in a series of steps, each of which takes some time.  The CPU can execute multiple instructions in parallel, but not all of the steps at once.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instructions are atomic and not splittable in any model of the
computation. For any sequence of instructions, it can be assumed that
the previous instruction has finished before the next instruction in
the sequence runs. However, many optimization techniques either
overlap instructions or split them into many microcode
instructions. Overlapping is also called pipelining and means that
instructions are split into several phases. The more phases, the more
instructions can execute concurrently. Microcode means that assembler
instructions are "recompiled" by the cpu into one or more microcode
instructions. For example, the x86 `rep movsb` instruction can cause
the cpu to execute hundreds of microcode instructions.